# How to group by ID and get the count per each category

Tags: pandas, group-by, count, categories

I got a df like this

```
    id  c1  c2  c3
0   0   11  12  0
1   0   15  15  1
2   0   4   24  2
3   0   5   13  2
4   0   3   15  1
5   0   5   7   0
6   0   3   18  2
7   0   17  9   3
8   0   0   17  1
9   0   12  0   0
10  1   17  9   3
11  1   1   21  2
12  1   0   3   1
13  1   4   20  3
14  1   8   22  0
15  1   16  23  2
16  1   0   3   1
17  1   4   20  3
18  1   19  17  1
19  1   12  0   0
```

For each ID, I want to count the values in c3 (see them as categories) and then divide the value by the length the id.

for example :
ID = 0 has 10 observations, 3 in c3.0,  3 in c3.1, 3 in c3.2, 1 in c3.3
ID = 1 has 10 observations, 2 in c3.0,  3 in c3.1, 2 in c3.2, 3 in c3.3

I want to obtain something like this :

```
ID c3.0  c3.1  c3.2   c3.3
0   0.3   0.3   0.3    0.1
1   0.2   0.3   0.2    0.3
```

The names of the columns are not relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [`groupby value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with `normalize=True` to count the occurences of 'c3' per 'id' normalized by total length of the group. Then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to get wide form:

```
out = df.groupby('id')['c3'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack()
```

`out`:

```
c3    0    1    2    3
id                    
0   0.3  0.3  0.3  0.1
1   0.2  0.3  0.2  0.3
```

---

Some cleanup with [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) to update the column headers, and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to make `id` a column:

```
out = (
    df.groupby('id')['c3'].value_counts(normalize=True)
        .unstack()
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .add_prefix('c3.')
        .reset_index()
)
```

`out`:

```
   id  c3.0  c3.1  c3.2  c3.3
0   0   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.1
1   1   0.2   0.3   0.2   0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `crosstab` :

```
result = pd.crosstab(df.id, df.c3, normalize='index')
```

Rename the columns:

```
result.columns = [f'{result.columns.name}.{label}' for label in result.columns]


result.rename_axis(None)
 
   c3.0  c3.1  c3.2  c3.3
0   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.1
1   0.2   0.3   0.2   0.3
```

Comment: This works as well but I prefer the other one